Should upload ipfs before calling contract to mint NFT or after?
I was learning web3 recently and I had a problem when I learned to mint a NFT.
There is a ERC721 contract and the baseUri is 'ipfs://xxxx/{tokenId}.json', and the tokenId is auto increament, which means invoke tokenId++ when calling mint function.
Based on this design, I should define metadata json file name with tokenId like '1.json', but I do not know what the tokenId will be before calling mint.
So I was wonder is it reasonable that calling mint function firstly and return a new tokenId then  upload metadata with name '{tokenId}.json' to ipfs, but it may cause other issues for example mint successfully but upload ipfs failed.
Any good suggestion? What are the common ways to do that?

The implementation completely depends on you.

You can upload the URI in a sequential way, 1.json, 2.json etc. But you said the token ID is not predefined.
You pass the URI while minting. Using the URI storage extension by OZ, you can pass the URI directly to the mint function. This means it will mint the token and set the token URI instantly in the same transaction.
The method you said seems a bit longer and inefficient route. Not something we see commonly unless the NFT is dynamic.

You can tweak the functions as needed. It's not necessary to use OZ if you're implementing on your own, but you can take the logic from there.

thanks for your answer,
for 1.  yes, token ID is not predefined, assume many accounts can mint at the same time, and considering tokenId generating will confict if upload a file with predefined tokenId name ;
for 2. yes, I have known this way,  but I still want to find a good way with increment tokenId, because  URI storage extension will store each token's cid, that may cause higher fee?? maybe?

If the token ID is being incremented sequentially? like 1, 2, 3 then what's the problem with the first approach? Is the token ID random?
Can you paste your contract, the relevant snippet only.

I just got a information that we can not upload files into an existed ipfs pinned folder, because the folder CID was generated and any files in the folder updated or added will change the folder's CID  [https://knowledge.pinata.cloud/en/articles/5593194-can-i-update-a-folder-that-is-pinned-on-ipfs], so the senario in my mind may not exist, which is different accounts upload NFT metadata files  into the same folder and the files' names are like 1.json 2.json ... , sorry for confusing you
